Blender 2.93 DupliVerts v Blender 3+ & 4+ DupliVerts Behavior
Does anyone know why the behavior of DupliVerts within the "Sapling Tree Gen" addon has changed in Blender 3 all the way to 4.2?
The DupliVerts work as expected when adding a custom leaf or branch in Blender 2.93, positioned correctly with a nice amount of randomness, whereas in any other version greater than 2.93 they don't.
Is it an issue with how DupliVerts work in Blender, or is it an issue with the Sapling addon?
The same results can be achieved using a particle system in 3+, however there is more setup required...is this maybe why DupliVerts have changed as they are outdated?
I've tried messing with the object data "Relations" axis, however the leaves/branches still don't behave correctly or as one would expect.
Here's an example of the results.


Dupliverts are sort of a legacy method, it is not deprecated yet, but has been superseded by Geometry Nodes, which is much more powerful and controllable at the expense of additional setup

Geometry nodes, of course that makes sense. Still wondering what the difference is between 2.93 and the newer versions regarding the way DupliVerts work...how did it break? If the Sapling Tree gen addon has continued to ship with Blender, why not make it work as it should.
